# Modificar archivo App settings extension .exe.config

Tags: c#

Cordial Saludo

Tengo una duda con respecto a leer y modificar un archivo de configuración que termina con extensión .exe.config desde C#, quiero poder acceder y comentar una línea y descomentar otra.

este es el código.

```
String SERVICEURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SERVICEURL"];
MessageBox.Show(SERVICEURL);
```

El archivo que genera por defecto el C# lo lee perfectamente, pero intento ingresar otro archivo para leerlo o modificarlo y no me funciona, como puedo pasarle alguna ruta para acceder y modificarlo?

Comment: Podrías dar un poco mas de contexto de para que la quieres comentar y des comentar?

Comment: La idea de comentar es para inactivar una linea y descomentar la otra, es como una especie de reseteo. son dos lineas que contienen una url, cuando una presenta errores entonces se activa la otra descomentandola.